# Set div width relative to window, not parent

Tags: jquery, html, css

I want to have a horizontal slider containing several divs. I want just 3 of them to be visible and want to use % (width 33%) and not px. My problem is that the slider (a jQuery plugin) adds a div with width:auto that is much bigger than the window and the 33% width of the content divs becomes relative to this parent and not the wrapper.

I cant achieve this in css as the content div must stay relative and not absolute.

The question is: Is it possible to make the width of the several content divs to be relative on load and resize to the width of the wrapper div that is 100% of viewport, and not of the parent?

I assume I should start with something like this, but do not know how to make it relative to the wrapper:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('.content').css( "width","33%" );
});
```

Answer (score 2):

In "modern" browsers use [**Viewport-percentage lengths**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/length#Viewport-percentage_lengths).

In your case `div.content {width: 33vw;}`

For non-supporting browsers there are some Polyfills. One you can find here: https://gist.github.com/LeaVerou/1347501

Answer (score 2):

You can just calculate a third of the viewport width each time, and use that:

```
$(window).on('load resize', function(){
    $('.content').css( "width",($(window).width()/3)+'px');
});
```

Also, as pointed out below by Deryck, you might be better off initialising this style using `$(document).ready(...)` rather than the `window`'s `onload` event, so:

```
$(window).on('resize', function(){
    $('.content').css( "width",($(window).width()/3)+'px');
});

$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').css( "width",($(window).width()/3)+'px');
});
```

Note: The window object is available instantly so the resize event handler can be attached either straight away or within `$(document).ready(...)`.

Answer (score 1):

BYossarian above me got it right but you also need to run the same function in a $(document).ready().

The code provided will only run on a $(window).on('load resize') event and not when the page is loaded initially.

fiddle:  http://jsfiddle.net/d9xuF/

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.content').css("width",($(window).width()/3)+'px');
});
```